# Calling function in the specified memory address. C++

Tags: c++, function, memory-management

I have been recently writing SEC algorithm (like here `http://18.7.29.232/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4015/HPCES024.pdf?sequence=2`). At first recursive version, which appeared to throw "stack overflow" exception for more then 200000 points. I hadn't known why till the time I have written it on my own stack (using iteration instead of recursion) and it worked fine for 1000000 points.

I believe that when I call function the instructions for processor and variables are copied to some "randomly" allocated memory. I think also that when I have got a global variable of class vector it needs to have some compact piece of memory (like table).

The problem is when I have a huge amount of function calls (for example in some recursive algorithm) because (in my opinion) when memory is split in small parts vector cannot "enlarge" and throws "stack overflow" exception.

So I thought that I could somehow persuade c++ where it should store functions instances memory. Like here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/placement-new.html make some table of "function instances", so it wouldn't be able to mess the memory.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is your vector a vector *of*? And how large is it? The best solution is probably just to use a more appropriate collection class.

Comment: You should always be careful when using recursion with large datasets, because the stack (which is used to store local variables, arguments and return addresses from the functions) is limited, and when you recurse to much you get a stack overflow exception. You can get by this by allocating data on the heap (using e.g. `new`) instead of using local variables for e.g. vectors or similar collections.

Comment: It uses 2 tables of 10^6 floats (= 8mb), one vector of int of maximal size of 10^6 elements (= 2 * 4mb) and in "main SEC function" one int (maximal recursive level is 10^6, which makes 4mb). Assuming, it uses 20mb + some memory for function calls. It is not much.

Comment: Then I doubt you've correctly analyzed the issue. But you can use [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) anyway since it won't hurt anything.

Comment: It made it even worse - when before it reached ca. 170000 in maximal function call deep before throwing the exception, now does it by 40000. I'll just stay with iterative version.

Comment: If you really have an iterative - rather than recursive - program getting stack overflow ... something is very wrong. You'd need to show some code and the error you get for us to help much more, though

Comment: When you call a function the processor instructions and variables are *not* copied to some random location. Without seeing any code it's very hard to say what the problem is, but I'm sure it's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's never the `vector` who gives a stack overflow error. `vector` allocates it's memory on the heap, which can get as large as your total memory (including virtual memory).

Stack, on the other hand, is a (rather) small piece of memory on which your program stores function local variables as well as other stuff.

When you call a function, these are some data that are written on the stack:

- Possibly some of the registers
- Stack pointer
- Possibly some space for return value
- Function arguments if any
- Base pointer
- The new function's local variables

Depending on the architecture/compiler, there may be other data as well.

So, even the simplest functions take a minimum amount of memory on the stack to get called. Fortunately, when the function returns, those memory are made available again. However, while this function hasn't returned, these data remain. So if you recursively call a function over and over again, all these data pile on each other. If you don't end your recursive function soon enough, you will run out of memory and you will get a stack overflow error.

If you are curious, you can add extra variables (making sure they don't get optimized out) to your function and see that you get this error with smaller number of points.

Your solution, has others have said in the comments is therefore to use an iterative approach, basically simulating the call stack using `std::stack` for example.

Comment: Ok, as I said before I have written the whole algorithm using iteration instead of recursion simulating stack on vectors (it works great, but code looks really bad). Just was curies why recursive solution does not work and hoped there is some smart solution to make it able to work in recursive way. And as I see there is none.

Comment: @PanJan, unfortunately you can't make the recursive work with too many iterations. The function frame (those data that I mentioned above) are an inevitable part of function calls.